# Modeling a category hierarchy based on a XML file

Tags: scala

I have a case class that that models the below XML file:

```
case class Category(id: Int, parent: Option[Category], name: String, children: Option[Seq[Category]])
```

Given the below XML file, how could I create a category that has the correct parent and children properties setup correct?

XML file that looks like:

```
val xml =
    <categories>
      <category id="1" name="rootNode">
        <category id="1.1" name="Preface">
        </category>
        <category id="1.2" name="Introduction">
        </category>
        <category id="1.3" name="Chapter 1">
          <category id="1.3.1" name="Sub Topic 1">
          </category>
          <category id="1.3.2" name="Sub Topic 2">
          </category>
          <category id="1.3.3" name="Sub Topic 3">
          </category>
        </category>
      </category>
  </categories>
```

Could this be done using recursion somehow?